# Where can I ask for package design suggestions?

Tags: discussion

TeX.SX doesn't seem the right place to ask for design suggestions for a particular package I'm planning to update at CTAN in the next few weeks. I believe this kind of question would flagged as too localized.

Now if TeX.SX is not suitable for this, in what forum or list devoted to LaTeX would it be permissible to ask for this kind of suggestion?

For example: *What name would it be appropriate to a control sequence that does such-and-such?*

Comment: What about the chat room?

Comment: This is not exactly an answer to your question, but you can probably get great insight from questions on the main site that are related to what your package does.